# Sum values of a Dictionary with "similar" keys Python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
CostofA = {'Cost1,(1, 2)': 850.93,
 'Cost1,(1, 2, 3)': 851.08,
 'Cost1,(1, 3)': 851.00,
 'Cost1,(1,)': 850.86,
 'Cost2,(1, 2)': 812.56,
 'Cost2,(1, 2, 3)': 812.65,
 'Cost2,(2, 3)': 812.12,
 'Cost2,(2,)': 812.04,
 'Cost3,(1, 2, 3)': 717.93,
 'Cost3,(1, 3)': 717.88,
 'Cost3,(2, 3)': 717.32,
 'Cost3,(3,)': 717.27}
```

From this dictionary, I want to create the following dictionary by adding up the elements that have **similar** keys. For example, I want to sum the values of `'Cost1,(1, 2, 3)'`, `'Cost2,(1, 2, 3)'`, and `'Cost3,(1, 2, 3)'` as they have the same numbers inside the parentheses `(1, 2, 3)` and create `'Cost(1, 2, 3)': 2381.66`. Similarly, `'Cost1,(1, 3)'` and `'Cost3,(1, 3)'` have the same numbers inside the parentheses, so, I want to sum `851.00` and `717.88` and write it to my new dictionary as: `'Cost(1, 3)': 1568.88`. For `'Cost1,(1,)'`, `'Cost2,(2,)'`, and `'Cost3,(3,)'`, I do not want to do anything but to add them to the new dictionary. If I can get rid of the comma right after the 1 in the parentheses, it would be perfect. So, what I mean is: `'Cost1,(1,)': 850.86` becomes `'Cost(1)': 850.86`.

```
CostofA = {'Cost(1)': 850.86,
 'Cost(2)': 812.04,
 'Cost(3)': 717.27,
 'Cost(1, 2)': 1663.58,
 'Cost(1, 3)': 1568.88,
 'Cost(2, 3)': 1529.34,
 'Cost(1, 2, 3)': 2381.66}
```

I know I can reach to the keys of the dictionary by

```
CostofA.keys()
```

and I know I may create a logic with a for loop and an if condition to create the above dictionary, however, I cannot think of a way to reach the numbers in the parentheses inside this if statement. Any suggestions?

Comment: show us how far you coded for the same

Comment: I think you should break the number 'Cost' string and the numbers into separate elements and give them separate keys. Your data could very easily be converted into a JSON type format e.g. `[{'Cost': 'Cost1', 'Numbers': (1, 2, 3), 'Value', 851.08}, ...]`

Comment: @chakri I couldn't do anything so far. How do I use JSON type to separate Cost1 and (1,2,3)? If I can do, I think I can compare them by saying if the parentheses parts are same, sum those and append to a list. Then, I would convert the list to my new dictionary. But still, I would be missing the new keys.

Comment: I could break the number 'Cost' and the numbers with `CostofA.keys()[i].split("(")` for every element in CostofA. Now, I cannot do the comparison. Any suggestion @StuartBuckingham ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one solution:

```
import re

str_pat = re.compile(r'\((.*)\)')

Cost = {}
for key, value in CostofA.items():

    match = str_pat.findall(key)[0]
    if match.endswith(','): match = match[:-1]

    temp_key = 'Cost(' + match  + ')'

    if temp_key in Cost:
        Cost[temp_key] += value
    else:
        Cost[temp_key] = value

CostofA = Cost
```

This creates a new dictionary `Cost` with keys built based on the numbers enclosed by brackets in the original dictionary CostA. It uses a precompiled regex to match those numbers after which it checks with `endswith(',')` if the matched pattern end with a `,` like in `(1,)` - if it does, it removes it.

It then explicitly  concatenates the pattern with brackets and other desired strings creating the target new key. If the new key exists, the program increases it's value by the value from the old dictionary. If it does not - it creates a new entry with that value. At the end, the program overwrites the old dictionary.

[re.compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) is a compiled regex object as said in the documentation:

> Compile a regular expression pattern into a regular expression object,
>   which can be used for matching using its match() and search() methods,
>   described below.

It stores a given fixed regex pattern for searching and is considered to be more efficient than calling a new regex each time, especially when the program does more matching with that same pattern,

> but using re.compile() and saving the resulting regular expression
>   object for reuse is more efficient when the expression will be used
>   several times in a single program.

Here it is used more for clarity as it defines the pattern once upfront rather then each time in the loop, but if your original dictionary was larger it could actually provide some performance improvements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Honestly, I couldn't understand the part: str_pat = re.compile(r'\((.*)\)'), even though I checked https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html.

Comment: Added the part on `re.compile`, it basically allows you to specify and fix a pattern upfront, which may be good for clarity but is also said to be good for performance in case of many searches with the same pattern. I'll update the doc references to python 3.

Comment: Or are you just asking about the regex pattern itself? Sorry if I misunderstood! This regex simply finds and returns everything that is between the brackets in the string one passes to it. I'm not a regex expert, but this one is very simple, so I can break it down for you if you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for you explanation @atru.

Comment: Glad to help, it was a nice problem :)

Comment: I have the continuation of the same problem that I cannot really do efficiently with my programming knowledge. I will add some other values from two other lists to these values based on a very similar logic. If you may also take a look at that I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735192/adding-dictionary-values-with-the-missing-values-in-the-keys) is the other question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Generate the items from the dictionary
2. Construct a list comprehension with tuple items by removing Cost.
   e.g., Cost1,(1,2) will be (1,2), and Cost2,(1,2) will also be (1,2)
3. Sort the list so all key items will ordered
4. Groupby using itertools and sum and store it in a dict

> ```
> from itertools import groupby
> data = sorted([(i[0].split(",",1)[1].replace(",)",")"),i[1]) for i in CostofA.items()])
> for key, group in groupby(data, lambda x: x[0]):
>     new_dict["Cost"+key] = sum([thing[1] for thing in group])
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much @chakri. Your solution looks shorter. Which one do you guys think more efficient? Since I will have higher dimensions, efficiency will be also important.