# Adding dictionary values with the missing values in the keys

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have the following three dictionaries:

```
Mydict = {'(1)': 850.86,
          '(1, 2)': 1663.5,
          '(1, 2, 3)': 2381.67,
          '(1, 3)': 1568.89,
          '(2)': 812.04,
          '(2, 3)': 1529.45,
          '(3)': 717.28}

A = {1: 4480.0, 2: 3696.0, 3: 4192.5}
B = {1: 1904.62, 2: 1709.27, 3: 1410.73}
```

Based on the keys in `Mydict`, I want to add the missing key value of `min(A, B)`. For example, For the first key `'(1)'` in `Mydict`, I want to add `min(A[2], B[2]) + min(A[3], B[3])` to the value of the first row and update the value in that dictionary. Similarly, for the value of the key: `'(1, 2)'`, I want to add the `min(A[3] + B[3])` as only `3` is missing in there. For `'(1, 2, 3)'`, I don't need to add anything as it involves all the 3 numbers, namely 1, 2,  and 3.Thus, my new `Mydict` will be as following:

```
Mynewdict = {'(1)': 3970.86,
              '(1, 2)': 3074.23,
              '(1, 2, 3)': 2381.67,
              '(1, 3)': 3278.16,
              '(2)': 4127.39,
              '(2, 3)': 3434.07,
              '(3)': 4331.17}
```

In this example, all the values of `B` are less than the values of `A`, however, it may not be the case for all the time, that is why, I want to add the minimum of those. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Will the keys always range from 1 to 3? Or you need a more general case?

Comment: I will need a more general formulation. They may range from 1 to 100. Thus, A and B dictionaries can include 100 elements for each.

Comment: There must be an easy way of reaching the numbers in keys by eliminating all other symbols. If we can do it, we may just create a list of possible numbers, e.g. [1, 2, 3] for this case, and then add min(A, B) based on whatever is missing. But, when there are symbols, such as single quotation mark and parentheses, I cannot figure out a way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of numbers sounds like a good idea, but to me it seems it will still require similar amount of (similar) operations as the following solution:

```
import re

str_pat = re.compile(r'\((.*)\)')

Mynewdict = Mydict
for key in Mynewdict.keys():

    match = (str_pat.findall(key)[0]).split(',')

    # set(list(map(int, match))) in Python 3.X
    to_add = list(set(A.keys()).difference(set(map(int,match))))

    if to_add:
        for kAB in to_add:
            Mynewdict[key] += min(A[kAB],B[kAB])
```

For each key in `Mynewdict` this program finds the pattern between the brackets and turns it into a list `match` split by `,`. This list is then compared to list of keys in A.

The comparison goes through sets - the program construct sets from both lists and returns a set difference (also turned into list) into `to_add`. `to_add` is hence a list with keys in `A` that are numbers not present in the compound key in `Mynewdict`. This assumes that all the keys in `B` are also present in `A`. `map` is used to convert the strings in `match` to integers (for comparison with keys in A that are integers). To use it in Python 3.X you need to additionally turn the `map(int, match)` into a list as noted in the comment.

Last part of the program assigns minimum value between A and B for each missing key to the existing value of `Mynewdict`. Since `Mynewdict` is initially a copy of `Mydict` all the final keys and intial values already exist in it so the program does not need to check for key presence or explicitly add the initial values.

To look for keys in `Mynewdict` that correspond to specific values it seems you actually have to loop through the dictionary:

```
find_val = round(min(Mynewdict.values()),2)
for key,value in Mynewdict.items():
    if find_val == round(value,2):
        print key, value
```

What's important here is the rounding. It is necessary since the values in `Mynewdict` have variable precision that is often longer than the precision of the value you are looking for. In other words without `round(value,2)` if will evaluate to `False` in cases where it is actually `True`.

Comment: One last simple question: when I search for the minimum value in `Mynewdict`, like `min(Mynewdict.values())`, it tells me the result. However, how can I see which key this result corresponds to without searching (ctrl+f) for the value and seeing the corresponding key?

Comment: Added, don't forget the round part :)

Comment: I see. Basically, we find the minimum value first, and then insert it into your added code inside the round function (of course, after rounding it). Once we run the code, it gives us the corresponding key with the value which is almost same as using ctrl+f. However, when the size is too large, ctrl+f actually does not work anymore. So, your method becomes my friend... Thank you very very much for all these @atru. Wishing the best for you!

Comment: Actually, instead of the number inside the round function, we can write `min(Mynewdict.values())` and remove the first step. Maybe, you meant it and I couldn't understand. But, now, it is perfect! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was rushing and did not see that you weren't looking for just any value, but  the minimum - updated with your suggestion which is actually good.

Comment: Glad it helped :)